# Invariance and Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $P$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathcal{S}$.

1. Show that $\mathcal{S}$ is invariant under a square matrix $A$ if and only if $AP=PAP$.
2. Show that $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}^{\perp}$ are invariant under $A$ if and only if $A$ and $P$ commute.

How should I start/approach to prove these two assertions? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x \in S$ **iff** $Px = x$.

(1)

> If $S$ is $A$ invariant, then $x \in S$ implies $Ax \in S$. Hence $APx \in S$ for all $x$ which means $PAPx = APx$ for all $x$, and so $AP=PAP$. If $AP=PAP$, then suppose $x \in S$ (and so $Px=x$). We have $APx = PAPx$, and using $Px=x$, we get $Ax = PAx$. Since $P(Ax) = (Ax)$ we have $Ax \in S$, and so $S$ is $A$ invariant.

(2)

> ! From the above, we see that $S^\bot$ is $A$ invariant **iff** $A(I-P) = (I-P)A(I-P)$, hence to finish we need to show that $A,P$ commute **iff** 
>   $AP=PAP$ and $A(I-P) = (I-P)A(I-P)$. Suppose $A,P$ commute, then $PAP = APP = AP$, since $P$ is a projection. The other equality follows since $A$ and $I-P$ commute and $I-P$ is a also a projection. Now suppose the two equalities hold. Expanding $A(I-P) = (I-P)A(I-P)$ we get $PAP = PA$, and the other equality gives $PAP = AP$ from which we get that $AP=PA$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{S}$ is invariant under a matrix $A$ iff
$$
A(x) \in \mathcal{S} \quad\forall x \in \mathcal{S}
$$
So suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is invariant under $A$, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $P(x) \in \mathcal{S}$, and so
$$
y := AP(x) \in \mathcal{S}
$$
Now $P$ is a projection, and so $P(y) = y$ for all $y \in \mathcal{S}$. Hence
$$
PAP(x) = AP(x)
$$
Conversely, suppose $PAP = AP$, then, for any $x \in \mathcal{S}$
$$
P(x) = x \Rightarrow A(x) = AP(x)= PAP(x) \in \mathcal{S}
$$
Since $P(y)\in \mathcal{S}$ for any $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now for the second part, use the fact that the projection onto $S^{\perp}$ is $(I-P)$.